# Install Apache virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have created a virtual machine (virtualbox) and I have to install apache2. do i need to install it before from windows or do i install it directly in the virtual machine?

sorry if this seems like a silly question, but I am starting this week with apache and virtual machines.

Comment: Install Apache where it is needed, i.e. windows or virtual machine

Comment: @JaromandaX ok thankss :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VM update the repos, install the apache server and start the server:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
```

Then you should be able to open a browser (In Ubuntu GUI) and go to `http://127.0.0.1` so see your apache-servers default page.

Look at [this link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#2-installing-apache) if you have any more questions.